# ASP.Net MVC 2.0 : unescaping URL query parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-encoding, urldecode

I have following URL:

`http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Cyan%ECde&realmId=1`

notice `%EC` in the value of `name` parameter.

%EC = 236 = **ì** (igrave)

In my action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name, int realmId) {...}
```

name[4] is a character with code 65533 (0xFFFD). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried decoding the name variable?

Comment: value is decoded for me by framework, I receive name value decoded already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the globalization element in web.config:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" />
```

Or if your site is UTF-8

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" />
```

But in this case the url needs to look like `name=Cyan%c3%acde`. You should always use URL helpers to generate urls so that they are properly encoded.

Comment: I don't generate URL. I give firefox:
http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Cyanìde&realmId=1
and it replaces "ì" with %EC

Comment: What happened when you set the `requestEncoding` in web.config?

Comment: @user93422 Interesting.  The link in your comment gets translated by Firefox as `http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Cyan%C3%ACde&realmId=1` for me

Comment: Putting iso-8859-1 (please correct your answer) fixes my original problem. But now it chokes on Г (UNICODE UTF-8 D090) since it (my program) treats it as two ISO-8859-1 characters (D0 and 90). Apparently the problem is that FireFox does encoding inconsistenly - sometimes it uses UTF8 sometimes it uses Latin-1. Any suggestions?

Comment: About translation, do you have any other language besides English installed? Could that affect firefox's encoding decision?

Comment: No, only English. Personally I would stick with UTF-8. No idea why FireFox encodes it this way.

Comment: If I enter `http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Cyanìde&realmId=1` and hit enter - ì is encoded as %EC, but if I redirect to that url or click on it as a link - then it is encoded as %C3%AC. Meaning that URL is encoded differently depending on how you got there.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that path is always encoded in UTF-8, only query parameters are encoded differently.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%EC")` gives that character (65533) as its output.

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ì")` produces `"%c3%ac"`

How are you generating this `%EC`?  It looks like your encoding isn't working as ASP.NET is expecting

**UPDATE**

You say that you're just entering `http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Cyanìde&realmId=1` into your browser and that it's not encoding correctly.  I would suggest that you shouldn't be entering that into your browser in the first place.  If you're generating that URL, you need to encode it (so that it renders as `<a href="http://localhost:8041/Reforge.aspx?name=Cyan%c3%acde&realmId=1">`). Firefox will show this with the ì when hovering over, but will give the encoded version when clicked or copied.

If users are typing arbitrary unicode into a URL, there's not a good way for you to handle that (since they're effectually sending you invalid requests).

Comment: Firefox replaces ì with %EC in the URL itself.

Comment: You are right, only if URL is entered manually FireFox uses ISO-8859-1 to encode, and only if non-ascii symbol is in query part (path is always encoded in UTF-8).

Comment: actually `HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%EC")` returns 65533 which is a pretty much "error character".

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem with url encoding (ì must be encoded as %EC to work) in ASP.NET and js.

If you set `<globalization requestEncoding="ISO-8859-1" responseEncoding="ISO-8859-1" \>` in `system.web` node, you must use `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode` to urlencode \ decode cause in this way you are using globalization settings in `web.config`.

Before using `UrlEncode` in current `HttpContext` I was using `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` that doesn't use current globalization settings.

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Some things I can find:

> HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(your param)
>
> HttpUtility.UrlDecode(your param)
>
> Server.UrlDecode(your param)

Any of these working for you?